# Is there a script to empty Google Team Drive Trash Related Folders?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How can I make a script to empty the google team drive trash folder? If I have three main folders in google drive, it makes three main trash folders. How can I empty all those folders?

All the scripts that I found only manage to empty the my drive trash folder.

I have already tried a lot of scripts as you can see the codes below

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('emptyThrash')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1)
      .create();
}
function emptyThrash()
{
Drive.Files.emptyTrash();

}


// I have also tried the script below
function doGet() {
  try{
  authorize();    
  var key = "YOUR DEVELOPER KEY";
  var params = {method:"DELETE",
                oAuthServiceName: "drive",
                oAuthUseToken: "always"
               };  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/trash?key="+key,     params);  
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail("<some email>", "EMPTY TRASH BIN ERROR:<br>"+error);    
    return;
  } 
}

function authorize() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("drive");
  var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?     scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### It is not possible to empty the google team drive trash folder directly.

What you can do instead is make use of the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22corpora%22%3A%22drive%22%2C%22driveId%22%3A%220AOfrSEwM6hQPUk9PVA%22%2C%22includeItemsFromAllDrives%22%3Atrue%2C%22q%22%3A%22trashed%20%3D%20true%22%2C%22supportsAllDrives%22%3Atrue%7D) the trashed contents of the team drive(s) and then permanently [delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete) those contents:

```
function myFunction() { 
  var optionalArgs={'driveId':'THE TEAM DRIVE ID', 'includeItemsFromAllDrives':true, 'corpora': 'drive', 'supportsAllDrives': true, 'q':'trashed = true' }  
  var trashed=Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs).items; 
  for(var i=0;i<trashed.length;i++){
    Drive.Files.remove(trashed[i].id, {'supportsAllDrives':true}) 
  }
}
```

For team drives, make sure to set `'includeItemsFromAllDrives':true, 'corpora': 'drive', 'supportsAllDrives': true` for listing and `'supportsAllDrives':true` for removing files. To query for trashed files only, use `'q':'trashed = true'`.

> Be aware that the contents will be deleted for all shared drive
>   members and to delete them you need to have the proper permissions (be
>   a manager or content manager).

Comment: Hello ziganotschka, thanks for the assistance. But an error appeared when I tried that scrpit: 

ReferenceError: "Drive" is not set. (line 3, file "Code")

Should we define 'drive' before?

I tried to put the driveId in this argument but also without success.

Comment: The problem was that I had forgotten to enable the Drive Api resource. Since I enabled it, the script worked fine. Thank you!