# How to empty trash for a Shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to empty the trash for a Shared Drive. There's no empty trash GUI button for those.
Thanks to SO I successfully connected Google Script with Drive so I can call:

```
Drive.Files.emptyTrash();
```

but that does it for my own Drive only (which also has GUI empty trash button anyway), not shared Drives.
So I'm trying to modify this code, also from SO:

```
Drive.Files.emptyTrash();

function myFunction() { 
  var optionalArgs={'driveId':'MY_NAME', 'includeItemsFromAllDrives':true, 'corpora': 'drive', 'supportsAllDrives': true, 'q':'trashed = true' }  
  var trashed=Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs).items; 
  for(var i=0;i<trashed.length;i++){
    Drive.Files.remove(trashed[i].id, {'supportsAllDrives':true}) 
  }
}
```

so I can try to call emptyTrash on a shared Drive. 'driveId':'MY_DRIVES_NAME' fails to resolve.
Any ideas?

EDIT: I now see emptyTrash is ment only for personal Drive, as per documentation. So the iteration method and  'q':'trashed = true' is the only way. Trying with these

Comment: Have you read this post already?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764248/is-there-a-script-to-empty-google-team-drive-trash-related-folders

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a script to empty Google Team Drive Trash Related Folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764248/is-there-a-script-to-empty-google-team-drive-trash-related-folders)

Comment: yes Gertjan and Rubén, i read these two links are where my code was copied from (specifically second part) but as I say, can't resolve driveId.
I'm going to keep trying with API documentation, which for me is a bit weird as no usage examples, and I'm thinking there's a mix of languages.

Also interating all files and letting all hopes for 'q':'trashed = true' to be up to date is scary. It doesn't seem a much secure method and woprry i could potentially delete everyth file!